# Setting log intervals on the x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there any way to make my x axis of the plot go from 0 to 10^5 in intervals of 10^n?

```
plt.plot(tau,c)
plt.xlim(0,1000)
plt.show()
```

I would like to add to this code.

Comment: Do you really want to have 0 as a limit or would also be 0.1, 0.001, etc... be posible?

Answer (score 0):

You can used `semilogx` instead of `plot` to make a plot with log scaling on the x axis.
See [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.semilogx.html) for this function's documentation.

You can then use `xlim` to specify the limits of the x axis. See [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlim.html) for this function's documenation.

Below is a code example of how to use both functions:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import electrocardiogram
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = electrocardiogram()
plt.semilogx(data)
plt.xlim(left=0,right=100000)
```

This code returns the following image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set a `log` scale to your axes. Here is an example:

```
plt.plot(tau,c)
plt.xscale("log")
plt.xlim(0,1000)
plt.xticks([1e0,1e1,1e2,1e3])
```

note: on a logscale you should not start with 0. Use 1 (1e0) or if you have values below 1, e.g. between 0.1 and 1, then use 0.1 (1e-1) as the first tick.